# Is it worth to have a static Builder class when I use Spring everywhere

Tags: java, spring

I use FooBuilder class to build objects of class Foo. `FooBuilder.create` accepts some initial arguments like `id` or `name`. The builder does not contain any state.

Normally I would do

```
class FooBuilder {
  public static Foo create(...)
```

but since the code base I work on uses [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) everywhere, is it still worth using `static` methods or better to make it not-static and use the Spring FooBuilder singleton?

Is there any argument for/against other than consistency with the rest of the code? Extensibility (+1 for Spring, can add some customization to the builder)? Testing (+1 Spring, difficult to mock static)? KISS (`static` is simple)?

**Edit:**

- Foo need to be built at compile time (`name` or `id` can change), builder stays the same

Comment: You might not want to get too dependent on Spring.

Comment: I'm confused -- are all your `Foo` instances able to be constructed at compile-time? Or are they dependent on runtime values?

Comment: Also unit tests shouldn't bother with an appcontext so a builder helps there.

Comment: Does `FooBuilder` only build a `Foo`, or is it similar to the `Collections` class which can build a ton of stuff? If it can only build `Foo`, what are you winning over a constructor, a(n internal) builder, or a static factory method in Foo itself?

Comment: The builder uses other objects to get `name` and `id` and `Foo` should not know anything about those objects, it is just interested in `name` and `id`. So I don't want to include this code into `Foo` static method

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Spring, it seems best to define it as a Spring singleton. This makes it easier to test other depending services by injecting a mock builder instead of the real one.

You might want to subclass the builder and override certain methods in the future, and with static that would not be feasible.

Also it's possible that you might want to apply some AOP to the bean such as logging, security or performance tracing in the future, and the use of static would make it harder.

In general it's more flexible to use Spring singletons, and it's better to try to reduce the use of static methods to very general utility methods only.

Also have a look at this post about [Tips for avoiding Static Method Overuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165595/tips-for-avoiding-static-method-overuse).